# Create / integrate a service extension

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

I need to create an extension in TYPO3. I created one using the kickstarter and built a service. Now I need to call the service on every page request. I tried to insert the service like i would insert a plugin;

> page.100 < plugin.tx_myext_sv1

or calling a userFunc

> page.100 = USER
>
> page.100.userFunc = tx_myext_sv1->process

but either one of them is working. How to do it the right way?

Comment: maybe i need to add that, when i include the lib before with includeLibs, it works. but it doesn't feel very clean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Just create a frontend extension, add a frontend plugin and check the example ts to insert it on every page.